# How can I select get the particular area, from an array, diagonally or other than horizontally?

Tags: python

I have a 4d dataarray of shape time,z,y,x = 96,40,500,500, as shown in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R78Kk.png), where time = 3 and z = 4. Now I want to select the highlighted part, how can I do that?
I can slice it horizontally, but how to do so diagonally or other than horizontally?

I tried
`plt.figure(figsize=[10,8],dpi=100)`
`tkt16l['REF'][3,5].plot.contourf(cmap='gray_r', levels=np.linspace(25,60,5), xlim=[-200000,150000],ylim=[-200000,200000])`

But it cannot be used to do so.

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you rotate the figure in such a way that the diagonal becomes horizontal, and then you can use `xlim, ylim` to zoom to the are of interest.

I have tried with yo given Image see the following:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot, transforms
%pylab inline
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage

image = cv2.imread('R78Kk.png')     # Change it to the image path
image = ndimage.rotate(image, -45)  # change the angle
plt.imshow(image, )
plt.xlim([200, 750])
plt.ylim([250, 500])                # add other constraints.


pyplot.show()
```

Results:

[image: Cropped and Rotated image]

The point to note here is,

You need to change the file the `xlim` and `ylim` as per your requirement. My answer was just to give you the idea

Comment: No dear, I don't want the figure to be cropped, I want to select the data, not the figure!! And if plot the data, this should be the result!

Comment: Okay that not a big deal from here, You got the cropped the image, you can just print that `image` variable, that will have the data of the region of interest.